# Object Representation - PHP

Tags: php, oop, object-model

I'm trying to understand how to best represent data which eventually I'll pull out and build JSON / XML from.. however I keep running in circles of how to define the object..

Essentially I want to represent a parent / child relationship along with what attributes are on the item.  Such that I could build a JSON or XML element.

Has anyone worked with something like this before or have any ideas on how to work through it?

My XML built would look something like:

```
<props>
  <items>
    <item id='foo'/>
    <item id='foo2' />
  </items>
  <bar>
    <test>
       <tree>This Data</tree>
       <tree>That Data</tree>
    </test>
  </bar>
</props>
```

I thought of some how trying to represent each data item in an object as:

```
class ItemResource {
  private $key;
  private $value;
  private $attribute_list = array();

  public function __construct($key, $value, array $attributeList=null){
      $this->key = $key;
      $this->value = $value;
      if($attributeList!=null){  
          //do stuff 
          $this->attribute_list = $attributeList;
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like an excellent job for PHP's [Array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). You can build infinitely large key-value hierarchies using associative arrays.

```
$itemresource = array(
    "key" => $key,
    "value" => $value,
    "attribute_list" => array(
        "foo" => "bar",
        "some" => "value"
    )
);
```

Associative arrays are also probably the input for XML generators (Although that's guesswork from my side)

You can also easily print your arrays out in JSON using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: The one bummer with arrays is I can't force a structure on it; which when trying to write out custom XML / JSON would make it harder wouldn't it?

Comment: @Fredrico: You could create a function or wrapper class that validates the structure of the associative array